# How to include random quotation in GMail signature

Tags: gmail

I have a file full of quotations that I would like to include in my GMail signature at random.  Is there a way to do this?

The random signature feature from Google Labs has been retired:
http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs-help-random-signature/browse_thread/thread/a816758b1f4d9b8e#

Answer (score 3):

I found a couple quotes from Steve Jobs and Joel Spolsky that I really liked, so I put them in my Gmail signature. I didn't want to forget them as I found other quotes, so I just added them in as well. However, now my signature is longer than the actual emails I was sending, so I, like the question asker, wanted a way to be able to collect my quotes and inject them randomly into my signature.

I couldn't find a working solution, so I held a little mini, solo hackathon in my apartment that started at about 10pm and ended at 3am, once I pushed the code to Github. You can download [Random Gmail Quotes](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/random-gmail-quotes) from my Github page and install it as an unpacked extension. To replace the quotes I picked, simply edit the quotes.js file -- in your user profile directory -- and replace them with your own.  **DISCLAIMER:** I wrote the extension.

There is another similar Chrome extension on the Chrome Web Store called [Random Quotes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/random-quotes/bhoalcabjhbiahfjlmhfcjkhfcdbfake), but it's two years old and stopped working. However, unlike mine, it has a nice UI where you can paste in your quotes. So, I installed it, figured out what the problem was, fixed it, and submitted a patch to the author's Github account. If you install this one, and you know what you're doing, you can swap out the bsearch.js file with the [one I submitted in the issue ticket I created on that author's Github account](https://github.com/raisen/Random-Quotes/issues/1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey @jmort253, does your extension include signatures / quotes in replies yet?

Comment: @WalrustheCat - No, it doesn't, because at the time it was just too much, and I did this in a little 8 hour mini-hackathon at 3am in my apartment.  I did what would provide value as a minimum viable product in the time that I had available.  I also didn't think it was possible to handle replies at the time in a manner that would be reliable, since Google doesn't actually load previous messages in the HTML page until after the user clicks the `...`.  At this time, I don't have plans to tackle replies; however, it's open source. You're welcome to try it out. :)  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the info.  i see several forks.  if no one has done it yet (let me know if you know anything) i just may give it a shot.

Comment: @WalrustheCat, I created an issue in the project repo, which describes the challenges and a possible solution to overcome it:  https://github.com/jamesmortensen/random-gmail-quotes/issues/3.  Let's move the discussion there off of Webapps SE.  Feel free to take a stab at it.  I'm willing to help with any questions or challenges you might face.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on [experimental new feature](http://lifehacker.com/395211/gmail-gets-13-experimental-new-features) and choose random signature.

That should do it.

Comment: This was new on: Jun 5, 2008 05:01 PM according the the date of the post.

Comment: The Random Signature Gmail Lab was retired some time ago.